# How to enable zooming in QtCharts?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I want to be able to zoom in my QtCharts using the mouse.

The best way to zoom using the mouse would be by drawing rectangles and adjusting the view to the new smaller rectangle.

How Can I implement this in QtCharts?

Highcharts has a very similar example and it looks quite nice:

[image]

Comment: Did you see this zoom example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-zoomlinechart-example.html?

Comment: @demonplus I tried that but it only lets me move the chart using arrow keys and zoom very slow using + and - keys. Mouse interaction does not work!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This functionality is provided by [QChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchartview.html#setRubberBand):

```
QChartView v;
v.setRubberBand(QChartView::HorizontalRubberBand);
```

There is also zooming out functionality [bound to your mouse](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchartview.html#mousePressEvent):

> If the left mouse button is pressed and the rubber band is enabled, ... the rubber band is displayed on the screen. This enables the user to select the zoom area.

Otherwise use the zooming functions in [QChart](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html).

Comment: Right Click zooms out (but does not reset).

Comment: Yes, for resetting you will have to bind a key or a mouse button to QChart::zoomReset()